# Wait Event in Application

Tags: c#, events

I want to wait for Event when I get data in my C# Project.

When program read some data *GetData* other program creates an event at the end of read this data (call *EventForGetData*).
So, I need to wait for EventForGetData that finish read.

I wrote this code for this task but believe this code might write more optimal.

```
        public static bool WaitEvent = true;
        public void EventForGetData(string variable)
        {
            WaitEvent = false;
        }

        public static string ForWaitGetData()
        {
            WaitEvent = true;
            while (WaitEvent)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);
                Application.DoEvents();                   
            }
            return Variable;
        }

        public object GetData(){
           // start read data
              ...
           // Wait for finish to read data 
           ForWaitGetData();

         // finish read data
              ...
          return MyObject;
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Task the first Task is to get your data, at the end do your processing or launch your event:
**Example**

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
              //put you code here the first one 
            }).ContinueWith((rs) =>{
              //Launch your event or anything you want
            });
```

**Note**: the code that you will put inside the ContinueWith will be executed after the code that you write in the StartNew.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how write it for my Example...             Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("");
                //put you code here the first one 
            }).ContinueWith((rs) => {
                ScriptInterface.ForWaitGetData();
                //Launch your event or anything you want
            });

Comment: If I'm fully understanding your code why you didn't organize your code like this http://pastebin.com/BTw6SZhF as long as you don't use Variable because returning no assigning variable have no sense.

Comment: Main problem is GetData() and EventForGetData() it's one and the same thread. Because one COM object generates EventForGetData() when I use GetData() . So, when GetData waits for Event , COM never calls function EventForGetData() if I don't use Application.DoEvent() while waiting it in GetData().

Comment: The general sense of code when I'm trying to get the value, but I can't get it until COM object itself does not give a value that must be obtained. That is, solutions to this problem must be implemented mechanism waiting for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it doesn't work.  If  ForWaitGetData() inserts  in Task sector Call function GetData()  freezes.

Comment: The GetData function freezes because of the waillAll calling, so if you wanna your program run faster without lagging there you can create another function to set or process the returned object and use continuewith like that:  http://pastebin.com/x6ySwSub

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109148/discussion-between-askeet-and-badro-niaimi).

Comment: I have opensource Project https://github.com/askeet/SwiffyToNet you can write it there in class ImportLib.cs. For check You need to run project and with help button "OpenHTML" select file swiffyToNet-master\Flash\ConvertExampleFla.swf, then press button "SetVar"